# Calling class function from another class. Error

Tags: java, function, nullpointerexception, extends

Simplified:
Two classes. X and Y.

Y extends X.

In X I call:

```
    Y periodic;
```

Then in X I call one of Y's functions:

```
periodic.conditionDepreciate();
```

The actual function block in Y is:

```
    public void conditionDepreciate() {
    ActionListener conditionDepreciation = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              if (ameba.health > 0) {
                  ameba.health -= 1;
              }
        }
    };
        new Timer(conditionDelayCount * 1000, conditionDepreciation).start();
}
```

But regardless of what the function does I get an error coming from the X file saying:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at X.(X.java:71)
>   at X.main(X.java:245)

Line 71 is referring to when I call:

```
periodic.conditionDepreciate();
```

Could someone help explain the error?

EDIT:

I want X to call various functions of Y. Which are all, basically, periodic event timers.

I originally had the timers in the X class file but to help with readability I moved into its own class file.

I'm not sure what something like this needs to be initialized with... Y extends X so it should get all its values from X? (I think...)

I posted one of the timer functions above - do I need to tell the Y class file what ameba.health is? or ? I guess I'll just have to look up functions and classes >.>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the value of `periodic` is null. That's the default for static/instance fields. You need to assign a non-null reference to it before you can call a method via it. We don't have enough information about what the value of `periodic` *should* be - whether you ought to be creating a new instance somewhere, or using an existing one - but calling a method on a null reference will give a `NullPointerException`...

If you tell us more about which instance you *expected* the method to be called on, we may be able to help further.

Note that the fact that `Y` extends `X` is irrelevant here.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm going to need to look into the basics of classes again... I added what I want it to do but I'm not sure what information you need to supply any detailed help.

Comment: @H.B.: You definitely need to go back and revise the basics. You need an *instance* of Y. It's not clear why you think that just because Y extends from X, you'll end up with a non-null reference by declaring a variable of type `Y`. Think about which *instance* of `Y` you're interested in.

Answer (score 5):

Seems to be a problem with `periodic` reference, as you never create the object, like

```
Y periodic = new Y();
```

Comment: Thank you, I did forget to add this but I didn't set up my Y class correctly so it appears I have another issue.